# Execution time of neo4j cypher query

Tags: neo4j, execution-time

I'm trying to find the execution time of GDS algorithms using the community edition of Neo4j. Is there any way to find it rather than query logging? Since this facility is specific to the enterprise edition.

Update:

I did as suggested. Why the result is 0 for the computeMillis and preProcessingMillis?

[image]

Update 2:

The following table indicates the time in ms required for running the Yen algorithm to retrieve one path for each topology. However, the time does not dependent on the graph size. Why? is it normal to have such results?

[image]

Comment: @tomaž-bratanič

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are executing the `mutate` or the `write` mode of the algorithm, you can YIELD the `computeMillis` property, which can tell you the execution time of the algorithm. Note that some algorithms like PageRank have more properties available to be YIELD-ed

- preProcessingMillis - Milliseconds for preprocessing the graph.
- computeMillis - Milliseconds for running the algorithm.
- postProcessingMillis - Milliseconds for computing the
  centralityDistribution.
- writeMillis - Milliseconds for writing result data back.

Comment: I tried it for the source-target shortest path algorithm. The result is 1 ms for the computeMillis property for all the graphs (6,301 nodes - 8,846 nodes - 10,876 nodes - 22,687 nodes - 26,518 nodes - 36,682 nodes - 62,586 nodes). Do you think this is accurate? while with Yen algorithm, the result of computeMillis varied between the graphs.

Comment: Yes I think this is accurate.

Comment: Is it beneficial to use the enterprise edition to get the query log which contains timing info? Do you think there is a difference between the two measurements (the way you suggested) and the query log using the enterprise edition?